# Как получит HWND окна при наведении на него курсора мыши?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

Как получить HWND окна при наведении на него курсора мыши С++ WinApi32 или Qt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `HWND`[`WindowFromPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms633558.aspx)`(POINT Point)` поможет вам.